# Grafana: Any way to integrate invite users with LDAP login

Tags: ldap, grafana

I am trying to configure Grafana for my organization. I was able to configure LDAP and MySQL database pretty easily but when I try to invite a new user to an org in Grafana, it always asks the user to join Grafana. 
This would be an OK behavior if at that point Grafana would authenticate against LDAP. Instead, it creates a new user in its own database. This would lead to conflict with LDAP in case the user's AD passwords changes.

This works perfectly when a user had previously logged in to Grafana. An invite sent after would directly take the user to login page.

Is it possible to do the same in case the user is not already registered in Grafana? I really want to avoid saving user credentials in Grafana database.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Grafana expert, but looking through the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/grafana/grafana) it certainly seems that new user registration will not go through LDAP. This is obvious in the LDAP related configuration file where you see the **read-only** credentials needed to look up users in the LDAP directory. A read-only administrator in LDAP **will not** be able to create new users as this would be necessary during a registration step. The code also indicates that registration creates temporary users in the internal store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bertold. Actually I do not want the new user to be created through LDAP, instead I would like an option Grafana to take the user to a login page when an invitation to join an org is sent. In case the user already exist in Grafana, in that case Grafana does take the user the login page, but not in case where it is a new user.